# How to nest my data by name on d3?

Tags: d3.js, nested

I can't figure out how to nest my data by name.

My data looks like this:

```
 var data = [
            [[{name: "Bonpoint"}], [
                {axis: "Coton", value: 1},
                {axis: "Laine", value: 0.8},
                {axis: "Cachemire", value: 0.6},
                {axis: "Soie", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Angora", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Autres", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Nylon", value: 0},
                {axis: "Acrylique", value: 0},
                {axis: "Viscose", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyuréthane", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyester", value: 0.20}]],

            [[{name: "Petit Bateau"}], [
                {axis: "Coton", value: 1},
                {axis: "Laine", value: 0.40},
                {axis: "Cachemire", value: 0},
                {axis: "Soie", value: 0},
                {axis: "Angora", value: 0},
                {axis: "Autres", value: 0},
                {axis: "Nylon", value: 0},
                {axis: "Acrylique", value: 0},
                {axis: "Viscose", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyuréthane", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyester", value: 0.20}]],

                ...etc
```

I tried this line of code:

```
var names = d3.nest()
              .key(function (d) {return d[0].map(function (o) {return o.name})})
              .entries(data);
```

But when I type `console.log(names)`, all I get is an array object and not the names directly. Do you have any idea how I could access directly the `name`s in my `data` ?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you put `names.key` in the console log?

Comment: @Ryan Morton: I've got an "undefined" message...

Comment: Looking at the JSON object more closely, it already looks nested.  I think you just need to map the object and set the key = name, second key = axis, and value = value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `object()` (or `map()`) instead of `entries()`:

```
var names = d3.nest()
          .key(function (d) {return d[0].map(function (o) {return o.name})})
          .object(data);

console.log(names.keys())
// =>  ["Bonpoint", "Petit Bateau"]

 console.log(names.Bonpoint)
 // => [[{name: "Bonpoint"}], Array]
```

Comment: Thank you Mark ! That's exactely what I was looking for. :)

Comment: wow, that was what I needed. in my case this reduces a foreach loop over 34000 rows to a simple line.